# The subnet ID 'aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id' does not exist status code: 400,

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to use AWS Auto Scaling Group (ASG).
How to correct an error?
Error: Error creating AutoScaling Group: ValidationError: The subnet ID 'aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id' does not exist
status code: 400, request id: 06571fdb-585b-486e-ae9c-19d3acb14d9e

...........................................................................
My code below:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "myvpc"{
 cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
 instance_tenancy = "default"
 enable_dns_hostnames = true
 tags = {
 Name = "newvpc"
 }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "firstsubnet"{
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  cidr_block = "192.168.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone1}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "secondsubnet"{
 vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
 cidr_block = "192.168.2.0/24"
 availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone2}"
 tags = {
 Name = "private_subnet"
 }
}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_igv" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "my_igv"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "my_route" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.my_igv.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "my_route"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet_assosiate" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.my_route.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "mysc1" {
  name        = "mysc1-http"
  description = "Allow inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "allow_http"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "wp" {
 ami = "ami-07d9160fa81ccffb5"
 instance_type = "t2.micro"
 vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.mysc1.id}"]
 subnet_id = aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id
 key_name = "MyKey"
 tags = {
 Name = "wordpress"
 }
 connection {
 type = "ssh"
 user = "ec2-user"
 private_key = file("./MyKey.pem")
 host = aws_instance.wp.public_ip
 }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "mysc2" {
 name = "mysc2-db"
 description = "Allow inbound traffic"
 vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
 ingress {
 from_port = 3306
 to_port = 3306
 protocol = "tcp"
 cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 }
 ingress {
 from_port = 22
 to_port = 22
 protocol = "tcp"
 cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 }
 egress {
 from_port = 0
 to_port = 0
 protocol = "-1"
 cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 }
 tags = {
 Name = "allow_db"
 }
}

resource "aws_instance" "db" {
  ami = "ami-07d9160fa81ccffb5"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.mysc2.id}"]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id
  key_name = "MyKey"
  tags = {
    Name = "mysql"
  }
}
output "instance_ip_addr" {
  value = aws_instance.db.private_ip
}


module "asg" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"
  
  name = "service"

  # Launch configuration
  lc_name = "example-lc"

  image_id        = "ami-ebd02392"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.mysc1.id}"]

  ebs_block_device = [
    {
      device_name           = "/dev/xvdz"
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      volume_size           = "50"
      delete_on_termination = true
    },
  ]

  root_block_device = [
    {
      volume_size = "50"
      volume_type = "gp2"
    },
  ]

  # Auto scaling group
  asg_name                  = "example-asg"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id", "aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id"]
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  min_size                  = 0
  max_size                  = 4
  desired_capacity          = 4
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = 0

  tags = [
    {
      key                 = "Environment"
      value               = "dev"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Project"
      value               = "megasecret"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
  ]

  tags_as_map = {
    extra_tag1 = "extra_value1"
    extra_tag2 = "extra_value2"
  }
}


module "elb_http" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/elb/aws"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  name = "elb-example"

  subnets         = ["${aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id}", "${aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id}"]
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.mysc1.id}"]
  internal        = false

  listener = [
    {
      instance_port     = "80"
      instance_protocol = "HTTP"
      lb_port           = "80"
      lb_protocol       = "HTTP"
    },
    {
      instance_port     = "8080"
      instance_protocol = "http"
      lb_port           = "8080"
      lb_protocol       = "http"
      #ssl_certificate_id = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:235367859451:certificate/6c270328-2cd5-4b2d-8dfd-ae8d0004ad31"
    },
  ]

  health_check = {
    target              = "HTTP:80/"
    interval            = 30
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 5
  }

  access_logs = {
    bucket = "my-access-logs-bucket"
  }

  // ELB attachments
  number_of_instances = 2
  instances           = ["i-06ff41a77dfb5349d", "i-4906ff41a77dfb53d"]

  tags = {
    Owner       = "user"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There reason for the error is that you are passing `strings` instead of actual subnet ids.

Thus, instead of:

```
vpc_zone_identifier       = ["aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id", "aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id"]
```

there should be:

```
vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id, aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id]
```

or

```
vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id}", "${aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id}"]
```

Comment: When I change this I have an error:
Error: Failure configuring ELB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: S3Bucket: my-access-logs-bucket is not located in the same region with ELB: elb-example
        status code: 409, request id: b3ac0d22-386e-46a1-9420-f0739652f390

Comment: Yes I know it but I have added the same subnets and security_groups for ELB but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @TJstock The error is about bucket, not subnets nor security groups. Your bucket for ALB logs is in different region. It must be in same one.